# sql group update column by age range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to update the class column of 33-year-olds as 2, 34-35-year-olds class column as 3, 36-year-olds class column as 4. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

```
ID DATE_OF_BIRTH CLASS
1  10.10.1986    1
2  11.02.1987    2
2  18.04.1988    3
.....................
.....................
.....................
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And what is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Please read the help center documentation on asking, especially on [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTableName
SET CLASS = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year, DATE_OF_BIRTH, GETDATE()) = 33 THEN 2
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(year, DATE_OF_BIRTH , GETDATE())  BETWEEN 34 AND 35 THEN 3
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(year, DATE_OF_BIRTH , GETDATE()) = 36 THEN 4
                 ELSE CLASS
            END
```

Comment: thank you. it's work.I am new this platform.

Comment: FYI, `DATEDIFF(year, DATE_OF_BIRTH, GETDATE())` Does **not** give someone's Age. For example, someone born on 31 December 2000 does *not* turn 22 on 01 January 2022.

Comment: Agreed, this should be `CASE WHEN GETDATE() >= DATEADD(year, 33, DATE_OF_BIRTH) AND GETDATE() < DATEADD(year, 34, DATE_OF_BIRTH) = 33` etc

Comment: Thanks, @Charlieface for the valuable information.

Comment: Thanks, @Larnu for the valuable information.

Answer (score 1):

You could update the table with a `case` expression over the calculation of the person's age:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET    class = CASE DATEDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, GETDATE()) 
                    WHEN 33 THEN 2
                    WHEN 34 THEN 3
                    WHEN 35 THEN 3
                    WHEN 36 THEN 4
                    ELSE class -- safeguard
               END
```